# Semi Monthly Date calculation in PHP

Tags: php, date, calendar

I am trying to calculate **Semi Monthly** dates,

- How to find given date is First half or Second half?
- First half **1 - 15**
  Second half   **16- End of the month**
  -

Comment: compare the day part of the date.... >= 16 is in 2nd half, else 1st half

Comment: What is your date format? `if (date('j') <= 15) echo '1st half'; else echo '2nd half';`

Comment: Date format mm/dd/yyyy , I have converted to Y-m-d for calculation.

Comment: It's working, Thanks Glavic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have getting the date and converted the date format to Y-m-d.

```
$pick_date = date( 'Y-m-d', $pick_date);
```

Then I have check the given date is 1st half or 2nd half.

```
if (date('j', strtotime($pick_date)) <= 15)
{
    echo '1st half';
} else {
    echo '2nd half';
}
```